# HP 4540s BIOS reset?

Tags: bios, reset

Product Name: Probook 4540s
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 8 (64-bit)

Hi,

HP Probook 4540, Hard disk 500 GB, RAM 4 GB, Video Card integrated simple. ***DVD ROM/Writer is corrupted.***

My brother purchased this laptop like 3 years ago, so the product is not in warranty. He used to sign-in through Hp protect tools fingerprint. Now these tools automatically set password for BIOS users. But he didn't set the BIOS administrator password back then. I tried to set BIOS Admin password thru BCU, it set the password but the option BIOS administrator was still not showing up.

He used laptop for 3 years, now its hard disk is problematic, system was hanging at boot where hp logo shows. I replaced the hard disk with a new one, it booted fine, but when I try to boot it from USB having an operating system, it says no bootable image found. I pressed f9 and to select the USB boot from boot options, there is no other option available then UEFI. UEFI is not working either. I can not get into BIOS as no password for BIOS Administrator was set before using HP protect tools. I can get into BIOS through simple users created by HP Protect tools, but it is not showing the boot options in BIOS.

I also tried this recently "power-button+Window logo key+b"

Hold them for like 3-5 seconds left it, and a message appeared after automatic resetart saying that a system bios recover has occurred. Then I tried to get into BIOS but the simple users are still there.

Please help me solve this issue. Contacting HP support is not possible as the product is no longer in warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Try popping out the battery for a few seconds and turn on the machone again.  If BIOS is not cleared, used the "sweater" method to attempt a BIOS reset. This method basically uses some kind of material to cover the laptop and force it to overheat. Upon overheating, HP laptops were programmed to shut down and reset BIOS. Passwords should be clear, and you should be able to set a new BIOS password.

Comment: I tried the battery method, it could have worked for the 1st generation, but it is a 4th generation machine. Anyway, the other method could burn the ICs I do not want to, causing it a permanent damage.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common in HP for some reason, last month i had same problem as you. What you need to do is to unplug cmos battery. Real pain it he ass, because you have to disassembly whole notebook for it. Taking battery out and hold power button don't work anymore. Or at least it never worked for me. Best thing to do is search on youtube video how disassembly your notebook, and go along so you don't damage anything. There is just no easier way that i know. Good luck!

PS: In HP laptos CMOS battery is often under the top panel where power button is.